# iOS - Delete row from UITableView crash

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift

I am trying to delete row from table view and core data the following way:

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, commitEditingStyle editingStyle: UITableViewCellEditingStyle, forRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyle.Delete) {
        managedObjectContext?.deleteObject(self.fetchedResultsController.objectAtIndexPath(indexPath) as! NSManagedObject)
        managedObjectContext?.save(nil)
        self.tableView.deleteRowsAtIndexPaths([indexPath], withRowAnimation: UITableViewRowAnimation.Fade)
        self.tableView.reloadData()
    }
}
```

But on `self.tableView.deleteRowsAtIndexPaths([indexPath], withRowAnimation: UITableViewRowAnimation.Fade)` my application crashes with the following error:

```
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Invalid update: invalid number of rows in section 0.  The number of rows contained in an existing section after the update (7) must be equal to the number of rows contained in that section before the update (7), plus or minus the number of rows inserted or deleted from that section (0 inserted, 1 deleted) and plus or minus the number of rows moved into or out of that section (0 moved in, 0 moved out).'
```

Maybe someone had something like this. Can anyone help me?

Comment: After deleting an object from managedObjectContext. Delete it from the array which you are using to load the table view cell.

Comment: Shouldn't be tableView: self.tableView?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After you delete a row, your function `numberOfRowsForSection` is called again. 
So by the time you delete the row, you should also update the value that you return in the aforementioned function.